# Bootstrap validator doesn't work in bootstrap modal ( the modal is inside a table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[I am using bootstrap3. I am trying to use bootstrap validator for forms in bootstrap modal window. My modal is inside a table. I have added all attributes required for validator but it is still not working. Please advice.(Hover my description to check out the image)](http://mile.mmu.edu.my/pillars2/image/ques.jpg)

My javascript code :

```
$(".category_form").bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        category_valid: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: "This field is required",
                }
            }
        },
        category_name: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: "This field is required",
                }
            }
        },

    }
});
```

HTML HERE with php :
[here is my html with php](http://mile.mmu.edu.my/pillars2/image/ques2.JPG)

Comment: could you post your html plz? just edit your answer to do this

Comment: hi , I already post the html code as a image, i cannot copy those code, there have some error in the description box , thanks for looking at it , appreciate

Comment: ah sorry, didnt see, i need a moment

Comment: thanks a lot , take your time , sorry for disturb

Comment: you should insert some attributes like "required" and the "has-error" classes. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation and here http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ did you try this?

Comment: sorry reply late , the question is , when i put the modal out of the table , the validation is work , but if i put inside the table , it doesn't work